# why maven deploy generate extra jars

Tags: maven, artifactory

I am trying to deploy my maven projects to private artifactory repository, but maven generated two jars with different version:

```
mvn deploy
```

[image]

why maven generated two jars for one deploy task? Is this a intentional act or bug?  my project has one parent pom with four child jar modules.

my parent pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.codingfarm.jsop</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsop-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <description>SOP协议Java实现，Maven父工程。</description>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <modules>
        <module>jsop-core</module>
        <module>jsop-client</module>
        <module>jsop-server</module>
        <module>jsop-bgzchina</module>
    </modules>
    <build>
        <!-- pluginManagement 中定义的插件将被所有模块继承 -->
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!-- 统一指定源码级别和编码，个别子模块可以覆盖 -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!-- 新版的Maven本身可能需要java 8才能运行，因此编译过程需要单独指定jdk toolchain，个别子模块可以覆盖 -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>toolchain</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <toolchains>
                            <jdk>
                                <version>1.6</version>
                                <vendor>sun</vendor>
                            </jdk>
                        </toolchains>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!-- Maven项目不再单独使用PMD P3C CheckStyle 之类的静态代码扫描，统一由SonarQube完成 -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.0.1398</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- 统一Site插件，生成构建报告 -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <locales>zh_CN</locales>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!-- 测试覆盖率检测 -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.8.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>report</id>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <!-- 依赖管理 -->
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- #### 单元测试 #### -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.12</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.stefanbirkner</groupId>
                <artifactId>system-rules</artifactId>
                <version>1.19.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>37382422b2a3-releases</name>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/local</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>37382422b2a3-snapshots</name>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/local</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

and one of child module pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.codingfarm.jsop</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsop-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>jsop-client</artifactId>
  <description>SOP协议客户端实现</description>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codingfarm.jsop</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsop-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: You have called `mvn deploy` twice. The format is `artifactId-Version.jar` where the version is `SNAPSHOT` which is replaced by a time marker `0.0.1-YYYYMMDD.HHmmss-#.jar`..so this means there is a time difference between the two calls of 7 minutes...this is no bug this the usual way SNAPSHOT are stored on repository managers...